# ng-repeat gets commented out by Drop.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm trying to make a dropdown menu using [Drop.js](http://github.hubspot.com/drop/docs/welcome/) and [Angular.js](https://angularjs.org/). When I try to use the `ng-repeat` directive inside a `content` element defined by Drop.js, the `ng-repeat` element just get commented out for some reason (see screenshot below). Anyone knows why this happens and what's a good way to solve this problem?

Screenshot of my DOM:

[image]

I also get an error in the console:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null

Here's my HTML code:

```
<div id="dropdownmenu">
    Dropdown Menu <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</div>

<div id="dropdownmenu-content">
  <div>Line 1 works fine.</div>
  <div>Line 2 works fine too.</div>
  <div>But lines in ng-repeat are not showing up!</div>
    <div ng-repeat="l in ['line 1', 'line 2', 'line 3']">
            {{l}}
    </div>
</div>
```

My JavaScript code:

```
var drop = new Drop({
      target: document.querySelector('#dropdownmenu'),
      content: document.querySelector('#dropdownmenu-content'),
      position: 'bottom left',
      openOn: 'click'
    });
```

[Here's a Plunker demo of my problem.](https://plnkr.co/edit/UcSC3x?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better bind `Drop` module after angular directive `ng-repeat` render over.

```
 angular.module('select', [])
    .controller('SelectController', ['$scope','$timeout', function($scope,$timeout) {

      $timeout(function(){
        var drop = new Drop({
           target: document.querySelector('#dropdownmenu'),
           content: document.querySelector('#dropdownmenu-content'),
           position: 'bottom left',
           openOn: 'click'
        });
      },0);

}]);
```

Comment: THANK YOU! This works for me! I still don't quite understand why $timeout solves my problem though. It seems to me the time delay is set to zero, why  does this makes binding Drop later than ng-repeat rendering?

Comment: DOM binding is depend on  DOM itself,and Angular rendering needs time.So , how could we bind DOM when it hasn't been rendered?Angular provides `$timeout` that we could know when the angular directive like `ng-repeat` has been rendered over.However the best answer is that not mixing angular with DOM handling.